# I am trying to use OnException for error handling in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, but I am getting an error: "No suitable method found to override"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, exceptionhandler, onexception

This type of error also appears when I try to use filter attribute (`[HandleError]`), not just that I'm not able to use HTML helpers like `@helper` tag.

I tried installing MVC from package console (according to Chat GPT) but that didn't work. I am using Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77847627/edit) so that it includes a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is your `[HandlerError]` attribute?  Pls share enough code. `not just that I'm not able to use HTML helpers like @helper tag` what is your target framework? Did you do any migration for the application or not?